# Concatenate rxjs Observables

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

Is it possible to concatenate multiple observables?

For example:
I have 3 function:

```
ensureUserLogged():Observable<boolean>

createEntity():Observable<Entity>

checkEntity():Observable<boolean>
```

I would like to do something like:

```
Observable.combine (ensureUserLogged(), createEntity(), checkEntity()).subscribe (
    checkEntityResult => console.log (checkEntityResult),
    error => console.log (error)
);
```

or something like:

```
ensureUserLogged().then (logged => createEntity()).then (newEntity => checkEntity ())...
```

Otherwise I need to write a ugly piramid:

```
ensureUserLogged().subscribe (
    res => {
        createEntity ().subscribe (
            res => {
                checkEntity ().subscribe (
                    res => { console.log ("I'm finally here") },
                    error {}
                )
            },
            err => {
            }
        );
    },
    err => {
    }
)
```

Is there something to achieve my will?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `Observable.forkJoin` for **parallel execution**:

```
Observable.forkJoin(ensureUserLogged(), createEntity(), checkEntity()).subscribe (
  checkEntityResult => console.log (checkEntityResult),
  error => console.log (error)
);
```

`checkEntityResult` will correspond to an array containing each elements: the first one for the result of `ensureUserLogged`, ...

To execute things **in series**, you need to use the `flatMap` operator:

```
ensureUserLogged().flatMap((resultOfEnsureUserLogged) => {
  return createEntity();
}).flatMap((resultOfCreateEntity) => {
  return checkEntity();
}).subscribe((resultOfChekEntity) => {
  (...)
});
```

You can notice that you can mix things. For example something like that:

```
ensureUserLogged().flatMap((resultOfEnsureUserLogged) => {
  return Observable.forJoin(createEntity(), checkEntity());
}).subscribe((resultOfCreateEntityAndChekEntity) => {
  (...)
});
```

Comment: Thank you, and what if createEntity (the second Observable) needs the result of the previous Observable?

Comment: EDIT: Thank you Thierry, so using flatMap the last subscription also contains any exception thrown by the previous methods?

Comment: In fact the result of the previous observable is what you receive as parameter of the flatMap callback.

Comment: With observables, error / exception are global to the chain. When subscribing at the end of the chain, the second callback will receive any error (from different levels)

Comment: They should have this kind of examples in the official documentation.